# How can I block this script manually?

Tags: adblock

I use wireshark to check network traffic made by firefox and discover some lines keep coming up every minutes, some of them are made by facebook, which is totally non-sense to me. I would like to block them but I don't want to block the whole domain of facebook, because most facebook element are made up by javascript, ajax, etc. I tried to block the scripts from the domain "www.facebook.com", it ends up facebook load nothing for me.

Those are some annoying request made by facebook every minutes:
GET http://0.255.channel.facebook.com/x/1692795768/1907440964/false/p_569545462=7 HTTP/1.1

I tried to use adblock plus to block it, by defining a rule to filter it, but these filter doesn't work, wireshark tell me the above request I mentioned is very active. These are some filter rule defined by me but failed:

*0.255.channel.facebook.com*
http://0.255.channel.facebook.com/*
http://0.255.channel.facebook.com/x/*

Moreover, I also dont want these request made by facebook:
POST http://apps.facebook.com/ajax/presence/update.php?__a=1 HTTP/1.1  (application/x-www-form-urlencoded)

POST http://www.facebook.com/ajax/chat/buddy_list.php?__a=1 HTTP/1.1  (application/x-www-form-urlencoded)

Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: just to be sure, is it seeing the requests and then dropping them? If so, it's working. Adding filters doesn't prevent the requests from facebook or other sites. You'll still see them. The filter just decides whether the request is accepted or dropped.

Comment: Note that this will disable the Facebook Chat instant messaging service, and probably some other things like automatic updating of your News Feed.  Also, the first URL looks randomly generated, so that rule probably won't do anything after awhile.